# How to host a phpmyadmin on dokku?

Tags: phpmyadmin, dokku

I have been searching everywhere but I did not come any good working method to host phpmyadmin on dokku.

I tried to different options but couldn't get to a working solution to host phpmyadmin and connect to mysql server on dokku.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just using MySQL Workbench connecting to my host via ssh. On the host, I exposed my mysql db to a port `dokku mysql:expose <db_name> <port>`.